# Glassfish 4.0 serializable coonection pools not working with Oracle XA transactions

Tags: oracle, glassfish, serializable, xa

I have a problem that I don't know how solve and researching the net has not helped me much. I declare in glassfish 4.0 asadmin console a serializable connection pool and its corresponding resource.

```
create-jdbc-connection-pool --datasourceclassname oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource --maxpoolsize 8 --isolationlevel serializable --restype javax.sql.XADataSource --property Password=A_DB:User=A_DB:URL="jdbc\:oracle\:thin\:@localhost\:1521\:orcl" ATestPool

create-jdbc-resource --connectionpoolid ATestPool jdbc/ATest
```

Then inside a stateless bean I build a datasource via jndi as follows:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
jndiDataSource = (DataSource) ic.lookup("jdbc/ATest");
```

and I'm getting connection as follows

```
jndiDataSource.getConnection();
```

Connections are properly obtained and released via finally clauses in each method we they are needed.
However, pairing serializable connection pool with XA data sources seems not to work, as getting first connections throws the following pair of exceptions in the order shown below

```
JTS5041: The resource manager is doing work outside a global transaction
oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110)

RAR5029:Unexpected exception while registering component 
javax.transaction.SystemException
at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:224)
```

with the following

```
RAR7132: Unable to enlist the resource in transaction. Returned resource to pool. Pool name: [ ATestPool ]]]
RAR5117 : Failed to obtain/create connection from connection pool [ ATestPool ]. Reason : com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: javax.transaction.SystemException]]
RAR5114 : Error allocating connection : [Error in allocating a connection. Cause: javax.transaction.SystemException]]].
```

Now if the connection pool is recreated without `--isolationlevel serializable`, then application works fine without any changes into the code. Also, if one keeps the isolation parameter and uses non-XA transactions as

```
--datasourceclassname oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
--restype javax.sql.DataSource
```

then again application works without any changes into the code.
I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what could be wrong in the above setup and how to actually make serializable work with XA data sources. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable useNativeXA.